# golang fx with flag parsing for configuration

Tags: go, dependency-injection, go-uber-fx

Using uber-go/fx, there's a vast amount of dependency injection going on where I use things like:

```golang
package main

import (
  "flag"
  "go.uber.org/fx"
  "github.com/peterbourgon/ff/v3"
)

func main() {
  fs := flag.NewFlagSet(_appName, flag.ExitOnError)

  var (
    httpHost = fs.String("http_host", "", "the host of the server")
    // ... imagine there are more flags
  )
  err := ff.Parse(fs, os.Args[1:])
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fx.New(
    fx.Supply(
      SomeConfig{
        Host: *httpHost,
      },
      // imagine there are more config structs
    ),
    fx.Provide(
      ProvideMux,
      // Imagine there are other providers being configured
    ),
    fx.Invoke(
      // start application
    ),
  ).Run()
}
```

What I'd like to do is something where my `SomeConfig` can be provided by using the flagset `fs` *but still validated with `ff.Parse`*. Is it simply too much to ask? Would a solution look at using modules that provide dependencies?

I've not tried to wrangle different provider functions, but I've tried to make config objects provided and the flagset as part of an Invoke.